# Using Erlang SSH Application to execute commands on remote UNIX Servers

Tags: unix, ssh, erlang, solaris, remote-server

I have always used the `os:cmd/1` method to call operating system routines. Now, i know that erlang has an `ssh` application. I would like to know how i can use this module to ssh into a SOLARIS server, run a command and collect the reply. I believe that such an operation would be handled asynchronously. I need an example using the ssh application built into Erlang doing this:

[image]

Now, at times we setup `SSH KEYS` between servers to prevent password prompt especially if one is using a script to execute tasks on remote servers. i am intending to write many Erlang programs or `escripts` that will interact with many remote servers within our environment. i need a complete example and explanation on how `ssh` with and/or without password prompt can be handled using erlang ssh application. 
 **NOTE:** In the screen shot above, the two servers had `SSH KEYS` set up and so there is no password prompt when ssh is initiated from any of the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct erlang native API to achieve this is **not** [ssh](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ssh.html), which only implements a user-interactive shell for ssh, but instead use [ssh_connection](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ssh_connection.html). Take a look at ssh_connection:exec/4

To be more complete, use ssh:connect to establish a connection and then using the handler returned from it to connect with ssh_connection:exec/4

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it myself and can't provide a complete example but [the documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ssh.html#connect-3) seems to be a good starting point.